# Insert hyperlink with text displayed instead of actual address

Tags: url

Is it possible to insert a hyperlink to a website in a buffer as one can do with texinfo `@url{http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu, GNU ftp site}` where text is displayed instead of the actual address?  My buffer in using `org-mode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `M-x org-toggle-link-display` to toggle the display of address part.

usually the address part is hidden by default.

in case you don't know the link format is `[[address][description]]`